# something went wrong with your request, please try again late Magento 2.4.5?

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend, onepage-checkout, magento2.4.5

I have Magento 2.4.5 and on checkout page I get this error
"something went wrong with your request"

I use one step check out and in that I got this error how can I resolve this ..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error backtrace, this issue is related to Meetanshi Extended Order Grid module, you can choose one of the following solutions that work for you:

1. Update Meetanshi Extended Order Grid module to the latest version, maybe the latest version of this module already fixed this issue.
2. Fix this issue by yourself. Hint: this issue comes from Meetanshi\ExtendedOrderGrid\Helper\Data, `getProductVailableQuantity` method.
3. Disable Meetanshi Extended Order Grid module.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the dependencies of the checkout page. You can do this by running the command "composer install" in the root directory of your Magento installation.

Comment: Thank You for Answer

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar issue on checkout page but i resolved this by restarting my elstic search using below command

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Then run the reindex command

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Thank You for Answer